# Using Regex to Compare and Compensate Missing Characters from 2 Strings to One Final String

Tags: c#, regex

I have 2 strings which comes from 2 different sources of machine readings for a code-line, but the readings are not always accurate and might get some missing characters. they both refer for a reading from the same code-line, but they use two different technologies of reading because both of them are not always accurate

The form of the strings should be like this example string:

```
string s = "<0123456<:012345678:00112233445566778899<";
```

but because of the accuracy, they could be like this:

```
string reading1 =   "?012?456<:012?45678:00112?33445566?78899<";
string reading2 = "??<0?23456??012?45676?00112?3344556?778890????";
```

where question-mark is unreadable character which can be from 0 - 9, <, :, or even can result from some noises which may occur at any of the start or the end of the code-line like in reading2

Also the numbers lengths can vary in each of the 3 parts in s string.

I am a new in Regex, and I need a way to use it so that I can get one final string that compensate the missing chars from both strings, so for the previous reading, the final string should be:

```
string finalString = "<0123456<:012?45678:00112?33445566778899<";
```

As the reading1 has the top priority so if the same char in both strings differs, the char in reading1 should be used like in the last 9 in the code line, and for non reading chars for both strings, it should remain as question-mark in final string.

I am new in using Regex so I am not sure if there is a way to implement this using Regex, I searched and found many Regex examples which no one of them like my problem, but some of them can solve only some parts of my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You've not stated anything about the device that is providing the data or how you  are getting the data. You should probably ensure that your getting good data rather than "guessing" what the data should be.

Comment: The device is getting the data through its API, so no way to do anything before getting the strings.

Comment: It seems to me that you would need some algorithm to align the strings so that you can work out if there are spurious characters at the start and end of the data. Perhaps the [Needleman–Wunsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) would work. Then you can compare the aligned data and prefer the characters from the first string where there is a difference.